# how to remove comment in comments of specific answer of specific question?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const QueryScheme = mongoose.Schema({
    Question:{
        type:String
    },
    identification:{
        type:String
    },
    postedBy:{
        type:String,
    },
    postedOn:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now()
    },
    likes:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    Priority:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    identification:{
        type:String,
    },
    answers:[{
        ansId:{
            type:String
        },
        postedOn:{
            type:Date,
            default:Date.now()
        },
        ans:{
            type:String
        },
        postedBy:{
            type:String,
            default:"singhal"
        },
        likes:{
            type:Number,
            default:0
        },
            comments:[{
                commentId:{
                    type:String
                },
                postedOn:{
                    type:Date,
                    default:Date.now()
                },
                postedBy:{
                    type:String,
                    default:"ayush singhal"
                },
                comment:{
                     type:String,
                }
            }]
    }]
})
```

this is schema of my project. how to remove `comment` in `comments` in specific `answer` in `answers`?
i have no more details about it.

Comment: Please don't post same text multiple times. and also leave out the fluff, and add actual useful details like what you have tried and what happened.

Comment: [`"arrayFilters"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) may be useful here.